# Nginx reverse proxy configuration for AWS web console

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

Is there a way to access AWS web console via nginx reverse proxy through my subdomain?

Here is the nginx configuration is have been using :

```
server {
  listen localhost:443 ssl;
  server_name aws1.subdomain.com;
  include snippets/proxy_ssl.conf;
  location / {
      proxy_pass              https://console.aws.amazon.com/;
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;

      proxy_http_version      1.1;
      proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header        Connection "Upgrade";
      proxy_read_timeout      86400;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_redirect          off;
      proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
  }
}
```

The above configuration throws:

> NetworkError: 400 Bad Request

And shows amazon's default 400 bad request page when i try to access https://aws1.subdomain.com in my browser.

Comment: Can you try `proxy_set_header Host console.aws.amazon.com`?

Comment: That would redirect to https://console.aws.amazon.com when i try to acess https://aws1.subdomain.com/. The idea is to access  https://aws1.subdomain.com/ but still be able to manage AWS web console.

Comment: I cant say for sure but what you're doing may not be supported, see: http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2014-April/043173.html. It has to with NGINX not supporting the connect HTTP method.

Comment: We have configured proxy for many SSL configured sites. Its seems to be working fine for those. But for https://console.aws.amazon.com it isn't working.

Comment: Thats interesting, its definitely not a standard use case for NGINX. My initial suspicion was that Amazon was getting a Host header other than console.aws.amazon.com and throwing the error as a result, hence my suggestion of changing the Host header on the proxied connection. Thats the only thing I can think of. Have you tried commenting out the proxy_set_header line? NGINX automatically changes the Host header to the name of the proxied server.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working using the following lines in nginx.conf. You can also add lines for http auth as required depending on your config.

```
location = / { rewrite ^ /_plugin/kibana/ redirect; }
location / { 
  proxy_pass https://<es-domain-url>.es.amazonaws.com; 
  proxy_http_version 1.1; 
  proxy_set_header Authorization ""; 
  proxy_hide_header Authorization; 
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
}
```